# JavaScript memory assignment

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am running into an issue where I am iteratively computing and storing values into different arrays in an object, but only the final iterations value end up saving in different parts of the object.

In the picture here, I have console outputed the values minY and maxY.

[image]

I then check the value that is stored in my array before I go to use it.

[image]

Is there any way around this? These values in the second picture are the ones that end up getting used, and it prevents me from moving forward.

EDIT: The loop I am using for assignment:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < partitions; i++) {
        var cellObject = new Object();
        cellObject.minX = sceneBounds.min[0] + boxLength * i;
        cellObject.maxX = sceneBounds.min[0] + boxLength * i + boxLength;

        for (var j = 0; j < partitions; j++) {

            cellObject.minY = sceneBounds.min[1] + boxWidth * j;
            cellObject.maxY = sceneBounds.min[1] + boxWidth * j + boxWidth;
            for (var k = 0; k < partitions; k++) {

                // int index = height*width*k + width*j;
                var index = partitions * partitions * k + partitions * j;
                cellObject.minZ = sceneBounds.min[2] + boxHeight * k;
                cellObject.maxZ = sceneBounds.min[2] + boxHeight * k + boxHeight;

                cellObject.objectList = [];
                cellArray[index + i] = cellObject;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not completely clear what you are asking, but it seems like a case of reference sharing.

Notice this:

```
a = b = {};
a.x = 7
console.log(b.x); // 7
```

or equivalently

```
a = {};
b = a;
a.x = 7
console.log(b.x); // 7
```

vs.

```
a = {};
b = {};
a.x = 7;
console.log(b.x) // undefined
```

Make sure you are not initialising "different arrays in an object" with the same literal.

Comment: I have added the loop I use. Does this look like what you are referencing?

Comment: Yes. You create one object per `i` iteration on your second line, then use that same object on your last line for each `cellArray` assignment in each iteration of `j` and `k`. The last line will not *copy* the `cellObject`, it will say `cellArray` is *that object* - the same one for all different `j`s and `k`s. You need to make a new object inside the `k` loop to have distinct non-shared objects. Use local variables to keep the values of `minX`, `maxX`, `minY` and `maxY` and only assign them to `cellObject` within the `k` loop.